# Blocking android MTP PTP USB access on rocky9

Tags: linux, rhel, removable-storage, mtp

I'm trying to block MTP PTP USB access from Rocky9.3 KDE OS I have tried.

- 1 through modprob.d
- 2 deleting USB driver from kernel

Not able to block the android USB on Rocky9.3.